# Reactions: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been developing a multipurpose bot both as a small side project, as well as to assist with the running of the Discord Server my University Society use, and after moving over from one static JS file to a modular approach I've encountered a few issues but this is one I haven't been able to crack.

The bot currently does 2 things with reactions, one of which works fine:

**1.** - Everyone someone DMs feedback to the bot, it posts this in a designated channel and adds a thumbs up, and a thumbs down that people can then voice their opinion with. This works fine, the reactions appear and there are no errors captured in the console.

**2.** - The bot creates a message on demand, and whenever someone reacts to that message, the bot sends a message saying "X reacted with Y", similarly if someone removes a react it says the opposite.

---

However, every time someone makes a reaction to this message, and turns out, to any message in a channel monitored by the bot, an error is logged stating that the ID of the Message the Reaction was on is undefined.

Below is the code of the `messageReactAdd` event, where if the ID of the message matches that of the one the bot is "watching" it will state someone reacted.

**messageReactionAdd.js**

```
module.exports = async (react, user) => {
    if(react.message.id === client.config.reactMsg)
        react.message.channel.send("<@" + user.id +">" + " reacted with " + reaction.emoji);}
```

Then to emit an event for each reaction so that they are captured even after a bot restart we have the raw event

**raw.js**

```
module.exports = async (client, packet) => {
if (!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(packet.t)) return;
const channel = client.channels.get(packet.d.channel_id);
if (channel.messages.has(packet.d.message_id)) return;
const message = await channel.fetchMessage(packet.d.message_id);

const emoji = packet.d.emoji.id ? `${packet.d.emoji.name}:${packet.d.emoji.id}` : packet.d.emoji.name;
const reaction =  message.reactions.get(emoji);
if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
    client.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
    console.log(reaction.message.id);
}
if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE') {
    client.emit('messageReactionRemove', reaction, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
}};
```

---

The actual error logged is as follow:

```
(node:15713) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at module.exports (/discord/events/messageReactionAdd.js:2:26)
at Client.emit (events.js:188:13)
at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at MessageReactionAdd.handle (/discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageReactionAdd.js:24:31)
at MessageReactionAddHandler.handle (/discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageReactionAdd.js:7:39)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/discord/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:188:13)
```

---

Initially even when the bot created its own reactions, only one would go through and an error was logged to state the ID couldn't be found, but since going async with the reaction modules that has worked fine and it's just user reactions that are no longer working.

(I also know I need to implement promises and catching due to relying on async/await)

**Updates - 24/01/19**
Based on the two comments so far (thank you!), when the `raw` event emits the reaction event, the objects in the `messageReactionAdd` event are both null/undefined, though are defined before/after emission in the `raw` event as suggested and backed up by extra logging.

I'm guessing it's to do with how I've implemented asyncronous as this all worked and continues to work when the bot is all in one static file, and seems like both events overlap or something - though I know very little about how this works in Node JS.

Comment: Looks like ```react.message``` or ```user``` isn't set correctly, they're missing the ```id``` property. Try ```console.log``` both of them and check if the data is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I've just done a log of both the User and Message ID in the raw event (They are both present and correct), and after when picked up by the event handler, at which point they both report undefined, so something's going wrong in picking up the event I presume

Comment: Are the `id` properties undefined or are the complete `react` and `user` objects undefined? Try to trace the steps and `console.log` a lot to determine where exactly the error happends, it'll give us more insight as to where the error occurs

Comment: Looks like the whole object is undefined as any tested attribute comes back undefined, and testing the object as a whole gets an unhandled promise rejection.
Having spammed a bunch of reactions at once, some come through and some don't so very intermittent